# Jquery: variable as ID selector not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, global-variables

Ok here is my code:

```
$tabularID = 0;
$('a.swfselector').live('mouseover', function(event) {
            $tabularID= $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $(this).parent().children().not(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                      $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.4)
            })
            $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                      $(this).fadeTo(100,1)
            })

    });
$('#' + $tabularID).live('mouseleave', function(event) {
            alert($tabularID);
            $(this).children().find('.tab').each(function() {
                      $(this).fadeTo(100,1)
            })

    });
```

Jquery doesn't like this selector:

```
$('#' + $tabularID)
```

Although if I change it to:

```
$('#27')
```

It alerts my variable $tabularID just fine, so I know it isn't the variable that is wrong (Output of $tabularID is 27). I need a variable here because the parent ID changes depending on which they mouseover.

Anyone can see what I can't? probably really obvious.

Comment: Not sure whether they're the root of your problem, but you mustn't use pure numbers as IDs. Prefix them with a letter like `a27`

Comment: Cheers for the info, although this doesn't fix the problem. What's the reasoning for this?

Comment: The specification ;) http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name Although I think in HTML5 it is allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ID must begin with a letter a-z or A-Z.

This code $('#' + $tabularID) is only affected at the first time you run it. It means your $tabularID = 0.

When you mouse over it only update the $tabularID value, but it will not update the binding to event of this object $('#' + $tabularID)

I think you can change your code like this:

```
$tabularID = 0;
$('a.swfselector').live('mouseover', function(event) {
            $tabularID= $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $(this).parent().children().not(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                      $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.4)
            })
            $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                      $(this).fadeTo(100,1)
            })

            $('#' + $tabularID).live('mouseleave', function(event) {
                alert($tabularID);
                $(this).children().find('.tab').each(function() {
                      $(this).fadeTo(100,1)
                })

            });

    });
```

Comment: Have you read the comments? OP already tried that and it did not work. Also it works if the ID is not in a variable, so this cannot be the problem.

Comment: I think that's it. Problem is that you will rebind the event handlers to the same element over and over again. You'd have to remove them too.

Answer (score 2):

I often use variables in selectors. And all works fine for me this way. Just avoid using IDs like '123'. ID naming rules:

- Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")
- Values are case-sensitive

Comment: I have changed the ID to meet this format and it still doesn't work :(.

Comment: Please post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ for example. Its better to see not only JS code but HTML code too.

Comment: As the OP already stated in the comment to his question, he tried this and it did not work...

Comment: That is very nice and works a lot faster than my version but for some reason it works on jsfiddle but not when I put it on my live site.

Comment: Works just need to replace the top with `$(document).ready()` Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this problem with jQuery. But found out that regular JavaScript DOM can handle ID's that start with numbers, if that's the problem. This might not help in this case, but it might be worth looking at if it is easier to change that piece of code, rather than changing how your ID's are set up.

```
document.getElementById(tabularID)
```

Note that you don't need '#' in the beginning.

[More info on document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)